# Hyperscript - How do i assign an event to a found element?

Tags: javascript, ejs, htmx, hyperscript

I have this event to specific input that works perfectly.

```
    <input name="company_addresses[0][vat_number]" id="company-profile-vat" type="text" class="form-control"
      value="<%=render?.data?.mes?.company_addresses[0]?.vat_number%>"
      _="on change make a Date called timestamp then put timestamp.toISOString() into the #company-address-updated.value">
```

But I want to assign this dynamically to several items.

So, on the top of the page, I made this script:

```
<div id="content-form" _="on load 
repeat for foreignInput in <input[name*='][']:not([name*='][serial_']):not([name*='][updated']), textarea[name*='][']:not([name*='][serial_']):not([name*='][updated']), select[name*='][']:not([name*='][serial_']):not([name*='][updated'])/>
  set inputTarget to foreignInput.name.split('][')[0]+'][updated' 
  repeat for foreignInputUpdateInput in <input[name*=`${inputTarget}`]/>
    log foreignInputUpdateInput 
     
    end
  end
end
">
```

so far, so good, I managed to get all the elements I wanted.
However, I want to assign the event to the found element, and I have no idea how.
I tried something like:

```
on change from inputTarget
  make a Date called timestamp then put timestamp.toISOString() into the foreignInputUpdateInput.value
end
```

but it doesn't work
I would like to avoid  if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different approach to the situation, instead of using the on-load event, and trying to set the event to a filtered element, I instead set my div to listen to every change, and then I filtered to get the source of the event that I wanted to apply the onChange event:

```
<div id="content-form" _="on every change  if event.srcElement.name.split('][').length > 1
                        set inputTargetString to event.srcElement.name.split('][')[0]+'][updated'
                        set inputTargetElement to <input[name*=`${inputTargetString}`]/>
                        if inputTargetElement != undefined
                        make a Date called timestamp then put timestamp.toISOString() into inputTargetElement.value
                        ">
```